# Invalid table-valued function EXTERNAL_QUERY Connect to PostgreSQL server failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I need to perform external queries from BigQuery to a Postgres instance.
I've set up a Postgres instance with a Public IP and an external connection on the BigQuery side in the same region (Frankfurt).

Whenever I try to perform a test query I get the following error:

```
Invalid table-valued function EXTERNAL_QUERY Connect to PostgreSQL server failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request. at [1:15]
```

Interestingly enough, a similar setup works well in another project. I don't understand what the difference is. There are no records in the error log of Postgres.

How could I debug what is going on?

Comment: If there really are no PostgreSQL log messages, it must be a network problem.

Comment: Seems like a permission issue, can you assign the  "roles/bigqueryconnection.serviceAgent" role  and try again?Let me know if this helps you or not.

Comment: @kiranmathew I'm trying to query from the Google Cloud Console. My user has already Owner privileges. So I guess it should not be a problem. Or what principal should I give this role to?

Comment: In the docs https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/connect-to-sql#access-sql is written, that one has to add a `roles/cloudsql.client` role to the service account, associated with the external connection. But I don't see any information about any service accounts on the contention details page.

Comment: Your service account may look like [this](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-agents#:~:text=service%2DPROJECT_NUMBER%40gcp%2Dsa%2Dbigqueryconnection) “service-<projectNumber>@gcp-sa-bigqueryconnection.iam.gserviceaccount.com” .This Service account needs to have the required [roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#bigqueryconnection.serviceAgent)  and the cloudsql.client role.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @kiranmathew suggested, a service account `service-<projectNumber>@gcp-sa-bigqueryconnection.iam.gserviceaccount.com` was missing. I tried to turn on and off the BigQuery connection API, but the account didn't appear. So I added it manually with the `BigQuery Connection Service Agent` role and my queries from the GCP console started to work.

Comment: Thanks! How and where did you create this service account?

Comment: @stujo I created a new principal here; https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam. Click "GRANT ACCESS", enter the email `service-<projectNumber>@gcp-sa-bigqueryconnection.iam.gserviceaccount.com` as principal and assign the `BigQuery Connection Service Agent` role. You should see this principal on the same page if you tick the checkbox "Include Google-provided role grants".

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. It's strange that SA hasn't appeared in the no lists. And even after being added with the proper role, the SA hasn't appeared anywhere. But it started to work.

Comment: @AlexanderGoida did you find how to display the SA? If it's can't be displayed, then how to revoke the granted role from the SA?

Comment: @masadamsahid it should be possible using gcloud CLI.